# Has anyone evaluated NuttX RTOS?

Tags: embedded

While reading Linux User's Journal today, I stumbled across a little blurb about [NuttX](http://nuttx.sourceforge.net) RTOS. I checked out their [website](http://nuttx.sourceforge.net) and was fairly impressed with its feature set and its ability to put it in an 8052! I find it interesting that it supports POSIX which is something I have helped worked on for one of my clients in-house RTOS. This one seems a little more feature rich than the in-house RTOS.

Has anyone else heard of NuttX and has given it a try? If so, how does it compare to other RTOS's such as [FreeRTOS](http://www.freertos.org)?

Comment: What toolchain do you want to use? What target device?  I decide on an RTOS based on its ability to work with my compiler, debugger, JTAG, and target CPU.  Yours?

Comment: Related, on [E&R](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/): [Has anyone evaluated NuttX RTOS?](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/2854/2118) :)

Comment: I downloaded a copy of the archive, and read the ReadMe, shortly after having a look at this question. I'm surprised by its flexibility as far as toolchain support is concerned (it supports certain existing cross-compilation toolchains, and a custom BuildRoot-based one that runs on both Linux and under CygWin), but I haven't got around to building it yet.

Answer (score 1):

NuttX and FreeRTOS are fairly comparable in regards to features.  It implements a standard UNIX device tree like FreeRTOS and has SD card support, serial port and a standard library.

Advantages of FreeRTOS are: It’s smaller (about 4kB min size, NuttX starts at about 20kB). Runs on more CPUs. Great forum too. However you start pretty much at zero. The NuttX 8051 port is complete and functional. But in order to make it useful, you would probably have to copy the whole stack on each interrupt as well to keep it from overflowing.

However with the time in market with FreeRTOS there are a ton of downloads out there already for it and considering it's tiny footprint I honestly wouldn't switch over yet until NuttX has been out there a bit longer.

My 2 cents.